# File path as user input in C

Tags: c, string, input, arguments, fopen

I couldnt find specific answer to my question. I am really low level, just started and had a class in which I learned to create file from the CodeBlocks. Took code with me home but it wont work because its not on the same computer. So, the idea was to make something that will allow user to choose path for the newly formed .txt file. When, instead of s, I manually insert "c:\example.txt" or something like that, the code creates a file "example.txt" but when I send it as input it simply wont. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *a=NULL;
    char s[50];
    puts("Enter the path of the file: ");
    fgets(s,50,stdin);
    a=fopen(s,"w");
    if(a==NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
        printf("Successful input");
}
```

Comment: So the entire problem was the `fgets` function which adds the `\n`at the end? Is there any other idea to make this work? It does the job but I simply want to make it as less complicated as possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the entire problem was the `fgets` function which adds the `\n`at the end? Is there any other idea to make this work?

You can replace the

```
    fgets(s,50,stdin);
```

with

```
    scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", s);
```

- this reads input excluding the `\n` into s, as long as its size allows, and consumes the `\n`, so that it doesn't get into the way of possible later input.

Comment: You can also just scanf "%s". Making sure input doesn't get too long etc. is always a it challenging, but if you trust the user and don't expect silly inputs (like in this case) that would be the most straightforward thing to do. (Another requirement is that the file path does not contain spaces, which your solution would allow.)

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider - _Another requirement is that the file path does not contain spaces_ - Where is that stated?

Comment: A requirement of my proposal, I meant. It is not part of the original question so that my proposal is not a complete solution (as opposed to your answer). My proposal is just very simple which is often nice for quick things like the OP's path input.